# ¿Como puedo saber cuantos checkbox tengo seleccionados en Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, datos

Primero que todo espero que se encuentren bien, formulo está nueva pregunta porque no encuentro como darle una lógica de programación a este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente, tengo una view en laravel el cual contiene una tabla que esta dentro de un formulario. El sistema es de repactaciones y el usuario tiene la posiblidad de seleccionar si quiere cancelar el total de la deuda o las cuotas que quiere por medio del checkbox.

Lo que quiero hacer es que se vaya generando, en un input de tipo hidden, el monto total dependiendo de las cuotas que va seleccionando. Por ejemplo, si marca solo las dos cuotas vencidas, que el input hidden quede con el valor de las dos cuotas sumadas, asi si marca tres, cuatro o el total de la deuda, para así enviarlo hacía el siguiente flujo y calcular los valores de descuento, cuotas dependiendo de las reglas de negocio de la empresa.

El codigo de mi plantilla blade es el siguiente:

```
<form action="{{ route('repactaciones.repactar') }}
" method="POST" >
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">TIPO</th>
            <th scope="col">CUOTA</th>
            <th scope="col">MONTO</th>
            <th scope="col">FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO</th>
            <th scope="col">DIAS VENCIDOS</th>
            <th scope="col">INTERESES</th>
            <th scope="col">GASTOS DE COBRANZA</th>
            <th scope="col">PAGO</th>
            <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($docs->data as $doc)
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->TIPO }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->CUOTA }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="h6">${{ $doc->MONTO }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="h6">{{ substr($doc->FECHA_VENCIMIENTO, 0, 10) }}</small>
                </td>
                <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->DIAS_VENCIDOS }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="h6">${{ $doc->INTERESES }}</small></td>
                @if ($doc->DIAS_VENCIDOS > 30)
                    <td>
                        <small class="h6">${{ intval(($doc->MONTO * 5) / 100) }}</small>
                    </td>
                @else
                    <td><small class="h6">$0</small></td>
                @endif
                <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->ESTADO }}</small></td>
                <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->PAGO }}</small></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="btnRepactar" class="btn-btn-danger">Repactar</button>
</form>
```

Entonces, a medida que vaya seleccionando quiero ver el monto total, por ejemplo si selecciona dos que aparezca un nuevo campo con el valor sumado de las dos cuotas seleccionadas.

Soy nuevo en Laravel y la empresa a la cual trabajo solicita este framework de desarrollo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacer una funcion en js y pasar el value del checkbox para que vaya sumando, si selecciona haces la suma pero si lo quita haces la resta, puede colocar un div para que vaya mostrando el resultado asi en una variable

```
 <form action="{{ route('repactaciones.repactar') }}
    " method="POST" >

<h5 id="total"></h5>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col"></th>
                <th scope="col">TIPO</th>
                <th scope="col">CUOTA</th>
                <th scope="col">MONTO</th>
                <th scope="col">FECHA DE VENCIMIENTO</th>
                <th scope="col">DIAS VENCIDOS</th>
                <th scope="col">INTERESES</th>
                <th scope="col">GASTOS DE COBRANZA</th>
                <th scope="col">PAGO</th>
                <th scope="col">ESTADO</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($docs->data as $doc)
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" onchange="myFuncion(this.value,{{ $doc->MONTO }});"></td>
                    <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->TIPO }}</small></td>
                    <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->CUOTA }}</small></td>
                    <td><small class="h6">${{ $doc->MONTO }}</small></td>
                    <td><small class="h6">{{ substr($doc->FECHA_VENCIMIENTO, 0, 10) }}</small>
                    </td>
                    <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->DIAS_VENCIDOS }}</small></td>
                    <td><small class="h6">${{ $doc->INTERESES }}</small></td>
                    @if ($doc->DIAS_VENCIDOS > 30)
                        <td>
                            <small class="h6">${{ intval(($doc->MONTO * 5) / 100) }}</small>
                        </td>
                    @else
                        <td><small class="h6">$0</small></td>
                    @endif
                    <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->ESTADO }}</small></td>
                    <td><small class="h6">{{ $doc->PAGO }}</small></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="btnRepactar" class="btn-btn-danger">Repactar</button>
<input type="hidden" name="valor-total" id="valor-total">
    </form>
```

luego generas un script, puede ser en la misma vista o por buenas practicas debería ser un archivo externo y enviarlo con un push en blade, pero asi te va funcionar

```
 <script> 
    var nuevoValor=0;
    myFuncion(valueCheck,valor){
    if(valueCheck){
      nuevoValo+=valor;
    }else{
      nuevoValo-=valor;
}
$('#valor-total').val(valor);
$('#total').text(valor);
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: A veces uno lleva tanto tiempo programando que la cabeza se nubla. Gracias por orientarme! Me has ayudado enormemente!

Comment: con gusto amigo